# Microsoft Sync Center not working properly after UNC path referencing was changed via gpo

Tags: group-policy, user-profiles, folder-redirection, offline-files, microsoft-sync

Anyone experienced Microsoft Sync Center Issues after move from a NAS to an EMC isilon based NAS (in the process changing Server Name & IP Address) resulting impact on Network shares UNC path name? We have certain users still having their home drive path referencing the old path ie (`\\server\oldshare` instead of `\\server\newshare` still being referenced). We ensured the old UNC to new UNC was properly defined and effected via GPO for Folder redirection. This policy has been enforced thoroughly on clients and tested after several updates and restarts.

Manually deleting the old references on client by IT support still results into conflicts and eventually rolls back after a while to referencing the old path. Our conclusion was [this](https://stealthpuppy.com/configuring-an-automatic-resolution-policy-for-offline-files-in-windows-7/) doesn't work properly on Windows 10.

The Client has no control over this since option has also been greyed out due to a global policy restriction making it impossible to effect this change on the client side of things. Is there any way this can be resolved via group policy via a global reg update setting? Do we have to re initiate offline caching on clients or via GPO? I also noticed that this has affected most clients migrating from windows 7 -> 10, most clients working offline or remotely via WiFi/VPN outside the corporate network or haven't been online for several days due to business travel.

We have also adhered to all best practices [here](https://4sysops.com/archives/folder-redirection-part-5-best-practices/).

I am thinking of possible scenarios via global policies - Reg Update of Offline cache paths from 7 -> 10 via GPO or manually via Clients?

Trigger manual offline sync cache process a step before or during the Migration process so Files are where they supposed to be when migration is done.

We have also found a script [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-sync-offline-files-0b2f0e96) which can trigger this cache manually but will require system privilege which the user doesn't have and we want to avoid having the user do this. We might probably include that in our migration process.

Is the information in [this article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9ce9195f-0aea-4019-84e5-13bd01e36b19/cannot-remove-offline-files-from-sync-center?forum=w7itpronetworking) relevant?

Comment: *We have certain users still having their home drive path referencing the old path...* Referencing it where? Please do not only respond in the comments. Instead, [edit] the post with this information.

Comment: @Twisty Impersonator updated

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sufficiently clear. Where are you seeing the old paths? In shortcuts? In Network Places? Where in Windows?

Comment: @Twisty Impersonator Since we are using offline cache in combination with Folder redirection the old paths referred to here are on a shared network Drive where the local folders such Documents, Desktop are redirected to e.g home_S$(\\sharename) . Answers your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the typical behavior of Offline Files (aka Client Side Cache or CSC).

Offline Files is intended to provide ongoing access to a remote share even when that share becomes inaccessible. Offline Files cannot distinguish between the share being inaccessible because it's simply offline or because the administrator has permanently decommissioned it. Further, it's notoriously difficult to delete an entire server or share path from the CSC, especially *after* the target has become permanently inaccessible.

The good news is that you can fix this as follows:

1. If possible, perform a full sync of the CSC in the Sync Center on the client and resolve any conflicts before permanently taking the share offline. (You've done this.)
2. Format the CSC database as follows:

   **WARNING:** Completing these steps removes all data stored in the local device's Offline Files Cache (the Client Side Cache). It does not affect copies of the data stored on the remote server. If you have unresolved sync conflicts, you will lose data that has not been synchronized to the server.

   1. Click **Start**, type `regedit` in the **Start Search** box, and then press **ENTER**.
      If you are prompted for an administrator password or for a confirmation, type the password, or click **Continue**.
   2. Locate the following registry subkey, and then right-click it:
      `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\CSC\Parameters`
   3. Right-click **Parameters**, point to **New**, and then click **DWORD (32-bit) Value**.
   4. Type `FormatDatabase`, and then press **ENTER**.
   5. Right-click **FormatDatabase**, and then click **Modify**.
   6. In the Value data box, type `1`, and then click **OK**.
   7. Exit Registry Editor, and then restart the computer.

[*Instructions from this Microsoft support article*](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942974/on-a-windows-vista-based-or-windows-7-based-client-computer-you-can-st)

Comment: Great feedback. Being unable to do backup of the CSC folder will i lose some Data during this process? If that will be the case how do i conduct a backup without having to take ownership as admin which i already tried which was actually taking forever. is there a special command or another workaround backing up the contents of this folder before resolving conflicts?

Comment: There are no supported methods for working directly with the CSC folder. Instead you could access the offline copies of the files through the Offline Files control panel app (or through File Explorer out even Command Prompt) and copy them elsewhere. Because this is a rather tedious process, it's clearly preferred to resolve all sync issues *before* taking a share Offline.

Comment: OK i will try all scenarios.